# How to return Package name and Checksum in AQL

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I am using a json file to populate my query that looks something like this:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "repo": "my-fake-repo",
          "path": {"$match": "my-fake-path"}
         }
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

I would like to include only the **name** of the files in that repo and their **sha256** sum. I've tried to use the .include() option, but it's not working for me. Any guidance on where to add the .include() tag with this structure? Again, using a json file to run jfrog rt s --spec option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax to get the SHA values of the artifacts within a repository.

```
curl -u testuser:testpassword -X POST -H "Content-Type:text/plain" -d 'items.find().include("name","actual_sha1","actual_md5","sha256")' http://art.local/artifactory/api/search/aql

{
"results" : [ {
  "name" : "log4j-core-2.15.0.jar",
  "actual_md5" : "81e0433ae00602c0e4d00424d213b0ab",
  "actual_sha1" : "ba55c13d7ac2fd44df9cc8074455719a33f375b9",
  "sha256" : "419a8512895971b7b4f4f33e620d361254e5c9552b904b0474b09ddd4a6a220b"
},{
  "name" : "log4j-core-2.15.0.pom",
  "actual_md5" : "41625b02e58659e1ca93934cfae05adc",
  "actual_sha1" : "6981c8f221fc6aba9797bb119b113eb392df6b2d",
  "sha256" : "7c74c42fd7abae9ba61068ea11fb2a65f13407704994bb65fb57916c96cdc75c"
},{
  "name" : "maven-metadata.xml",
  "actual_md5" : "085d0609db2dc21acd69e92e49d4536e",
  "actual_sha1" : "e7265bab56759973893a1942a9cb1d70ed624c79",
  "sha256" : "8b973243eedee7eb8708f305f1cf8215bf57714167545eb6a3c2a98891d43677"
} ],
"range" : {
  "start_pos" : 0,
  "end_pos" : 3,
  "total" : 3
}
}
```